# Set value in correct position in string

Tags: c#, html, string, forms, loops

I am trying to build a string and set the value (0 or 1 radio checkbox) in the correct position of the string. It's building the string and setting the value according to array position I need to set it from a given ID position. The ID position is set in int accessID

```
Response.Write(perm + " - " + Request.Form[perm] + "<br />");
```

This write output is:

```
access_1 - 0
access_30 - 0
access_6 - 1
access_34 - 0
access_31 - 0
access_37 - 0
access_2 - 0
access_23 - 0
access_28 - 0
access_35 - 0
access_36 - 0
```

And

```
Response.Write(inputPerms + "<br>");
```

Write will output:

```
0#0#1#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#
```

access_6 has a value set to 1 because in the table I checked a radio input on the 3rd row so it has set it in the 3rd position of the string. It works in this order, I am trying to set it in the string according to the access ID position. So access_6 needs to set 1 in the correct position, this case should be 6th, what must I do to set the value in the correct position of the string. The output string should be this instead: (access_6) 6th position:--

```
0#0#0#0#0#1#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#
```

Hope this is clear, thanks for any help. Here is the code:

```
if (Request.Form["updatePerm"] != null && Request.QueryString["action"]=="update")
{
    foreach (string perm in Request.Form)
    {
        string input = perm.Substring(0, perm.IndexOf("_") + 1);

        if (input == "access_")
        {

            string accessRef = perm.Replace("access_", "");
            int accessID = Convert.ToInt32(accessRef) + 1;

            Response.Write(perm + " - " + Request.Form[perm] + "<br />");

            string chkInputs = Request.Form[perm];
            inputPerms += !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(chkInputs) ? chkInputs + "#" : "";

        }
    }

    Response.Write(inputPerms + "<br>");
}
```

Comment: If you already know the number and inputs and it doesn't change, you can create a fixed array (`int[] accessArr = int[30]`) and use `accessID` as the indexer when setting. If you know the `foreach` will always give the values in order, just use a `List<int>`

Comment: thanks I can sort of understand but don't know how I can implement this are you able to show me how?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
           string[] input = {
               "access_1 - 0",
               "access_30 - 0",
               "access_6 - 1",
               "access_34 - 0",
               "access_31 - 0",
               "access_37 - 0",
               "access_2 - 0",
               "access_23 - 0",
               "access_28 - 0",
               "access_35 - 0",
               "access_36 - 0"
                           };
            string inputPerms = "";
            foreach (string line in input)
            {
                inputPerms += string.Format("#{0}",line.Split(new char[] {'-'}).Skip(1).First().Trim());
            }
            Console.WriteLine(inputPerms);
            Console.ReadLine();
```